# Bounties broken network-wide

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

An attempt to set a bounty on any question results in 404 at the URL

```
{site}/posts/bounty/start/{post-id}
```

`{post-id}` being the actual post id.

I haven't tried every SE site, but given that this occurs on Mathematics and here on Meta...

Comment: Originally reported [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20039/147263)

Comment: Now also reported on [meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288666/cannot-add-a-bounty-to-question-getting-a-404-page-when-i-try)

Comment: Also happens SO.

Comment: confirmed on Mi Yodeya too

Comment: confirmed on Earth Sciences

Comment: Also reported on [Puzzling.SE](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2871/39).

Comment: I don't believe it's necessary for a representative of every SE site to confirm that their site is affected...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi of course not, but admit it, it's fun ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (rev `2015.3.25.3204` on meta, `2015.3.25.2409` on sites).

To verify that the fix actually works I urge you to award me a bounty.

Comment: First make exception on this question to overcome the 48 hours block... ;)

Comment: It'd suffice to open one (which was the error in the first place), and accept my answer, the rest is _magic_

Comment: But a bounty can't be even started within 48 hours. Sorry, no bounty for you.

Comment: @m0sa - I believe Shadow is talking about the 2 day waiting period before one can start a bounty on a question.

Comment: haha, as usual @Oded got me right. Great minds....

Comment: in hindsight, I should've let the bug be for another 2 days... I'll remember that for the next time :P

Comment: But I think the real question is.. are there any checks if I manually send the POST request? :p

Comment: Look I'm not being funny but how come you guys don't have regression tests for this stuff???